# Camera.pixel(Height/Width) doesnt match the Canvas size Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, viewport

I am making an app that has a custom viewport Rect like so:

[image]

When i check the sizes of this viewport rect in pixels with the following function in c#: `Camera.pixelHeight; Camera.pixelWidth` i get the following values: 743px, 770px.

This looks correct. 
Now when i check my canvas in the Editor i see the following values for the width and hight.. See img below

[image]

No i have a script that gets the width and hight of the Canvas.. This is correct i get again the 743px and 770px. But when i position my UI element it is outside because the positioning refers back the the incorrect values displayed in the Canvas Rect Transform properties.

**Edit:**
Maybe it has something to do with how i position the element. I do it in the following way atm:

```
sl.position = new Vector3(200, -200, 0);
```

this position should be relative to the anchor point of this element in the Canvas.

What is happening here and how do it make the canvas use the correct values?

Comment: I do it like so: `Debug.Log("Viewport size: "+c.pixelHeight);` and c is a reference to the Main Camera in my scene (i only have one camera)

Comment: ah sorry didnt understand u correctly. Here is how: `var ViewPortSizes = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;`

Comment: that has to do with the size of the UI element right? According to the docs at least..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176679/discussion-between-futurecake-and-programmer).

Comment: There's still a bit more information you could supply. Are there scalings applied up the hierarchy that could be affecting the values?  I use RectTransform.localPosition just fine, so positioning elements shouldn't be an issue, but be aware of the affects of the hierarchy. I previously asked if you were referencing the correct camera. That might still be an issue if your "Main Camera" is not the one you're talking about here in your post.

Comment: That value in canvas is provided based on current editor Game mode resolution and not camera resolution. Your Gamemode might be having a free aspect or something which is different from the values you are recieving from camera. If you want to fix it then use the standard settings of aspect ratio which 16:9 or create your own resolution ie 1920*1080 which by again refers to 16:9 aspect. You can also adjust canvas scaler from constant pixel size to Scale with screen size. Scale with screen size will allow your canvas to adjust itself as the name suggests.Try this and let us know if need be.